# Comparing unix timestamp dont return the expected result - JAVASCRIPT

Tags: javascript, datetime, unix-timestamp

I have a unix timestamp property in my database propertyName is **closeDeal**.

**closeDeal** value in database - 1624699800 (unix timestamp). What I'm required to do is have two validations on the above timestamps

1. the **closeDeal** timestamp is greater than the current timestamp
2. the **closeDeal** timestamp should be >= currentDate_StartTime and <= currentDate_EndTime

Here the **currentDate_StartTime** would be the start time of the current date i.e (0,0,0,0)

Here the **currentDate_EndTime**   would be the start time of the current date i.e (23, 59, 59, 999)

**What I tried.**

Below is my code of converting the currentDate to unixtimestamp and comparing.

**Helper functions**

```
getStartDateTimeStamp() {
        let currentTime = new Date();
        currentTime.setHours(0, 0, 0, 0);
        return Math.round((currentTime).getTime() / 1000);
    }

getEndDateTimeStamp() {
    let currentTime = new Date();
    currentTime.setHours(23, 59, 59, 999);
    return Math.round((currentTime).getTime() / 1000);
}

getCurrentDateTimeStamp() {
    let currentTime = new Date();
    return Math.round((currentTime).getTime() / 1000);
}
```

**Date comparison in business logic**

```
if(
   closeDeal > this.helper.getCurrentDateTimeStamp() // check if close deal is greater than current date
&& closeDeal >= this.helper.getStartDateTimeStamp() // closeDeal greater = than current Datetime
&& closeDeal <= this.helper.getEndDateTimeStamp() // closeDeal less = than current Datetime
 ) {
        //some logic here.
```

}

But the above code always fails

Comment: do you get errors in the console? Did you check that those hlpers are getting referenced? The code looks fine

Comment: Can you show the values each function produces? The logic looks correct, unless there's possibly a timezone issue here. One small issue (certainly not the problem you're having) is that I'd do `new Date()` only once, so it doesn't have any chance of changing in value from one instance to the next.

Comment: The timezone issue is that the way you're using `setHours()` depends completely on the default timezone where the code is running, which might not be the timezone `closeDeal` was collected in.

Comment: "It fails" is not sufficient. Provide sample input, actual result and expected result. In *getEndDateTimeStamp*, setting the milliseconds to 999 then dividing by 1000 and rounding is equivalent to `currentTime.setHours(24,0,0,0)`. Similarly in *getStartDateTimeStamp*, because the hours are set to `0,0,0,0` rounding is redundant.